# how to get value of variable in jacl scripting language for IBM WebSphere Plugin Custom Properities?

Tags: websphere, wsadmin, jacl

I used the below code to get input from the user using jacl scripting language

`set pname [gets stdin]

    $AdminConfig create Property $pluginname {{validationExpression ""} {name $pname} {description ""} {value "30000"} {required "false"}}`

I can't able to get a value of variable `{name $pname}`. I shows the error as attribute name is invalid.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since braces prevent substitution, you could do:

```
$AdminConfig create Property $pluginname [list {validationExpression ""} "name $pname" {description ""} {value "30000"} {required "false"}]
```

I think an easier pattern to remember is the one you'll see [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tsec_SPNEGO_tai_enable.html)

```
set attr_name           [list name $pName] 
set attr_value          [list value 30000] 
set attr_required       [list required false] 
set attr_description    [list description ""]

set attrs [list $attr_name $attr_value $attr_required $attr_description]

$AdminConfig create Property $pluginname $attrs
```